# Smarty show only one iteration of matching string

Tags: smarty

I don't even know if I'm asking for the right thing. What I have is a list of categories and those categories will be links to filter items. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
{foreach from=$items item=entry}
{strip}
    {foreach from=$entry->categories item='one_category'}
         {foreach from=$categories item='one'}
              {if $one_category.name == $one.name}
                  {$one.name}    
                  {$one.name|munge_string_to_url} 
              {/if}
         {/foreach}
     {/foreach}
{/strip}
{/foreach}
```

Here's a better version:

So this lists out every instance used on a page. The intention is to list the instance 1x, if there is an instance.

```
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
    {foreach from=$items item=entry}
    {foreach from=$categories item='one'} 
     <li><a href="#" data-filter=".{$one.name|munge_string_to_url}">{$one.name}</a></li>
    {/foreach}{/foreach}
  </ul>
```

This shows all the items but it's not correct, if there are 20 articles assigned to one category, it lists it 20 times, if there are 5 articles assigned to one category it will list it 5 times. I just want one each for each matching string. Not a clue as to what to do. Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Let me know if I'm following you here...You take each entry. Loop through it's categories. Then loop through another list of categories you set outside this code somewhere. Then check to see if the entries categories match the categories listed in $categories. Printing out the category entry from the list created outside this code for each match?

Comment: First is the main list of categories entry->categories. Then it looks for each category name that's the second for each. Basically this bit of smarty is supposed to be used within an item associated with a category, not outside it, but here I just want a list of categories of those items on the page so I can create a filter list.

Comment: So this lists out every instance used on a page. The intention is to list the instance 1x, if there is an instance. 
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
  {foreach from=$items item=entry}
  {assign var='munge' value=0}
{foreach from=$categories item='one'} 
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".{$one.name|munge_string_to_url}">{$one.name}</a></li>
{/foreach}{/foreach}
</ul>

Comment: Are you using the News module for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this.

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
    {assign var="tempCat" value=""}
    {foreach from=$items item=entry}
        {if $entry->categories} 
        {strip}
            {foreach from=$entry->categories item='category'}
                {if !$tempCat|strstr:$category.name} 
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".{$category.name|munge_string_to_url}">{$category.name}</a></li>
                    {assign var="tempCat" value=$tempCat|cat:$category.name}
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        {/strip}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Basically, the idea is to keep a record of categories you've already added to the list and not add them again. I do this through $tempCat which starts as nothing and concatenates any category that's not in it. So subsequent checks see the category is already added and skips it.

Comment: I wish it was. It works only if there are items on the page assigned to the categories, it doesn't base it's navigation on what is on the page. I'm looking at a jquery route, quicksand auto builds the navigation based on the information on the stage, so I'm going to figure out how isotope can do it even if I have to hire a jquery person. Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI: What I'm trying to do is this:

      http://spab-rice.com/wordpress/rawa/

Notice the filters. When you go to the next page, it builds them by those on the page, not what categories you have.

Comment: I didn't see this. I will check it out when I get back late today! Thanks so very much!!!

Comment: You rock! Thank you so very much. It works great, even on the second pages. Are you available for hire for other smarty stuff?

Comment: My company doesn't allow me to freelance. But I can be 'hired' through them...http://www.liquid-creative.com

Comment: Dang. You are very swift. Here's my site: dropsoul.com. I wish I could hire you from them. But alas, not now.